# Calling a device function from global function

Tags: c, cuda

How should I acces 'do_sth' function in 'print' function (look at the code)? Why there is 'N' (look at the code) variable/constant visible to GPU without using cudaMemcpy?

```
 __device__ void do_sth(char *a, int N)
 {
         int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
         if(idx < N)
         {       
                 a[idx] = a[idx]; 
         }
 }


 __global__ void print(char *a, int N) 
 {     
         //question_1: why there is an access to N, it is now in GPU memory, how?
         int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

         //do_sth<<<nblock2,blocksize2>>>(a,N); //error_1: a host function call can not be configured
         //do_sth(&&a,N); //error_2: expected an expression

         if(idx<N)
         {       
                 a[idx]=a[idx];
         }
 }
```

Comment: Your question is vague, please elaborate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `__global__` function (aka "kernel") resides on the GPU already. All its parameters (variables `a` and `N`) are passed through shared or constant memory (depending on your device type) upon the call, so you can directly access those variables. There is a limit of parameters size - 256B on pre-Fermi cards and <strike>16KB(?)</strike> 4KB on Fermi, so if you have big chunks of data to transfer, you cannot avoid `cudaMemcpy` functions.
- `__global__` function parameters should not be modified.
- When calling `__device__` from `__global__` you do *not* specify the configuration parameters in the triple brackets. The `__device__` function will be called by all threads that reach the call from the kernel. Note that you can call functions from within `if` statements, to prevent some threads from executing it.
- <strike>In current version of CUDA it is impossible to spawn more threads during kernel execution.</strike>
- There is no unary `&&` operator in CUDA C++ (there was no such operator in normal C++, not sure about it now when the new standard emerges)

Comment: according to the programming guide at http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf compute 2.x capable devices get 4KB